# Avoiding having emails being traced

Tags: email, microsoft

I am writing a novel and the main character sent anonymous emails using Outlook and a VPN on an iPhone to disclose information about the mafia. Now, the police are investigating it. How can he avoid getting attributed to the emails? Is there anything he can do?

The police sent a request to Microsoft. Everything is taking place in Italy and I checked laws in Italy, and it looks like it takes them 3 weeks to get info to the police.

I need a credible story and for him not to be caught. The police are corrupt!  Oh, and he closed his Microsoft account, but those stay open for 60 days, apparently. What can he do?

Comment: When you say "Outlook", you mean Outlook.com? How do you mean "anonymous"? How was it sent "anonymously"?

Comment: Basically, the main character sent an email from an account he created and then closed. The police is trying to find him. He used microsoft outlook.

Comment: Outlook is a program and an email provider service. Which are you talking about?

Answer (score 2):

The police trace the email account that sent the emails (i.e. Microsoft, in this case) and contacts the email service for information. The email service checks its logs for the IP and any other information tied to the account and the device that sent the emails. The account might be closed but the logs last far longer than the account.

The police then trace the IP to see where it was sent from. In this case, it will be a VPN, but most VPNs keep logs, so the police can get the real IP of the user. The police take this IP and go to the mobile phone provider and ask who was using that IP at the time the email was sent, and the mobile provider gives the police the user's account.

I would suggest that the character not send emails the way you outlined if they do not want to be caught. Use Tor on a desktop to contact a secure email service like Protonmail and send emails from there. Services like Protonmail do not collect user data and Tor masks all the IP traffic. The police won't have anything to trace at any point.

There are also other things the character could do to be even more secure, but for the purposes of a novel that isn't about security techniques, Tor and secure/anonymous email services are enough to be plausible that the police won't find the character.

Comment: +1 for 'Use Tor on a desktop to contact a secure email service like Protonmail'.  OP, Tor anonymizes the user's connection to the email service.  So, if the user connects to the email service through Tor (and always/only through Tor, including during creation of the account), the email service can not trace back to the user.  The email service doesn't have to be ProtonMail, but most other mainstream services (Gmail, YahooMail, etc.) to not allow connections through Tor.  ProtonMail does, and even offers a .onion site for this purpose.  See https://protonmail.com/tor.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to go on Tor and buy access to a compromised computer (e.g. rent a botnet, do some forensics on it, then take over one of its nodes). Connect to that computer from Tor, use it to connect to a free webmail service like outlook.com, and do your business.

Self-destruct software on the compromised host would be set up to prevent logging and remove evidence. The police can get as far as the compromised computer, and, with help from the ISP, they can learn that it was controlled from the dark web.